# Rails 3 No such file to load -- Nokogiri (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I get the following error:

```
/srv/www/cyprus-weather.net/cyprus-weather/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-

3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:306:in `rescue in depend_on': 

No such file to load -- Nokogiri (LoadError)
```

only when executing **production** environment (for example: `rails c production`). In development mode all works well.

Anyone knows what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`require 'Nokogiri'` must be `require 'nokogiri'`. The name is case-sensitive.

Your dev env is on Windows, which has a case-insensitive filesystem, so you didn't catch this error in development.

*(Don't see any other way why this might be happening)*

Comment: I develop on a Mac. However, I will check this asap

Comment: @Zack, the answer stands, but then I have no idea how it might had worked.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem as well and it wasn't case insensitivity.  I did however have to include rubygems just above this line.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
```

Happy coding!

Comment: +1. Even though probably different from the OP problem, this helped me!